# Joining two linux scripts

Tags: linux

I have a friend who needs to join two scripts in linux and I don't have any idea how. Could anyone please help us out? The scripts are below

```
#!/bin/sh

if ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c oscam     >/dev/null
then
echo "oscam... ok"
else
echo "oscam... restarting"
/var/bin/oscam &
fi
```

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Stop oscam"
killall -9 oscam 2>/dev/null
  sleep 2
 echo "Start oscam"
 /var/bin/oscam &

exit 0
```

Comment: What does your "friend" mean, exactly, when he says he wants to join these two scripts ?

Comment: Lets look: Script 1: If oscam isn't running: run it. Script 2: kill oscam. start oscam.  What do you really want?

Answer (score -1):

remove 2nd occurrence of "#!/bin/sh". Your combined script would look like below

```
#!/bin/sh

if ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c oscam     >/dev/null
then
echo "oscam... ok"
else
echo "oscam... restarting"
/var/bin/oscam &
fi

echo "Stop oscam"
killall -9 oscam 2>/dev/null
  sleep 2
 echo "Start oscam"
 /var/bin/oscam &
exit 0
```